# Generate .ics on the fly with symfony2

Tags: symfony, icalendar

I am using this [bundle](https://github.com/markuspoerschke/iCal) 
for .ics generation.  The only issue is that the file is saved as 'filename.ics.html'.  I have checked and it seems I am the only one having this issue.  I tried removing the .html extension but calendar can't open it saying, it's not recognized.

Am using Symphony 2.8 and mac.

Code: (A copy and paste from the source)

```
public function icalAction($id = 0)
    {
        $vCalendar = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Calendar('www.example.com');
        $vEvent = new \Eluceo\iCal\Component\Event();
        $vEvent
            ->setDtStart(new \DateTime('2012-12-24'))
            ->setDtEnd(new \DateTime('2012-12-24'))
            ->setNoTime(true)
            ->setSummary('Christmas')
        ;
        $vCalendar->addComponent($vEvent);
        header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cal.ics"');
        echo $vCalendar->render();
    }
```

Comment: You'll have to include your code and what you've done if you want some help. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I used [Bomo/Ical](https://github.com/BorisMorel/IcalBundle) bundle and it works well. (I juste comment it as you may want to try other bundle)

Answer (score 3):

Did you try returning a proper Response?

```
return new Response(
    $vCalendar->render(),
    200,
    array(
        'Content-Type' => 'text/calendar; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="cal.ics"',
    )
);
```